# Trying to make a function as robust as a website (BASE64)

Tags: powershell

If I give this site https://www.base64decode.org/ data like `NnFjamFvOGw5NnA1Y2Y2MHNtamlxb2drNzVfMjAyMTEwMjFUMTcwMDAwWiB`

I get a result like `6qcjao8l96p5cf60smjiqogk75_20211021T170000Z`

if I run the following PS lines

```
$Encoding = 'default'
$Result = [System.Text.Encoding]:: $Encoding.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('NnFjamFvOGw5NnA1Y2Y2MHNtamlxb2drNzVfMjAyMTEwMjFUMTcwMDAwWiB'))
```

I get error

```
Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array 
or string."
At line:1 char:1
+ $Result = [System.Text.Encoding]:: $Encoding.GetString([System.Conver ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

I even tried to pad the line which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't depending on the line. (I am unsure why the padding is not always working)

```
function Get-PaddingRequired {
            param (
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
                [String]$InputString
            )
            $modulo = ($InputString.Length % 3)
       
            switch ($modulo) {
                0 { $paddingRequired = $null }
                1 { $paddingRequired = '==' }
                2 { $paddingRequired = '=' }
            }
            Return [string]$paddingRequired
        }
```

Running `NnFjamFvOGw5NnA1Y2Y2MHNtamlxb2drNzVfMjAyMTEwMjFUMTcwMDAwWiB` in my padding function above. I sadly only get one `=` the correct answer seems to be `==` which is confusing.

There should be a better way to become more robust like the site https://www.base64decode.org/. Ideas ?

Comment: The padding function looks Ok to me. Your sample string is 59 chars, so `=` is the correct padding to make it divisible by 3.

Comment: Mistake here: `$Result = [System.Text.Encoding]:: $Encoding.GetString(` should be `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString(`

Comment: Your cited website omits unprintable bytes. That makes you think that a wrong BASE64 string is correct. I would not consider this more "robust". `NnFjamFvOGw5NnA1Y2Y2MHNtamlxb2drNzVfMjAyMTEwMjFUMTcwMDAwWiB=` is the correct BASE64 string. Use https://www.utilities-online.info/base64 to see the difference.

Comment: @zett42 we agree. but when I put ```NnFjamFvOGw5NnA1Y2Y2MHNtamlxb2drNzVfMjAyMTEwMjFUMTcwMDAwWiB=``` into ```$Encoding = 'default'
$Result = [System.Text.Encoding]:: $Encoding.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('NnFjamFvOGw5NnA1Y2Y2MHNtamlxb2drNzVfMjAyMTEwMjFUMTcwMDAwWiB='))``` I still get the error as written in my question.

Comment: You have a space in front of `$Encoding.GetString(...)` which shouldn't be there

Comment: @Theo nice! Make that an answer. Also, I added ```If ($TestURI.Length -gt 60) {
            $TestURI = $TestURI.Substring(0, 60)
        }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is caused by a simple typo

Remove the space you have in front of `$Encoding` here:

```
$Result = [System.Text.Encoding]:: $Encoding.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(...))
#                                 ^
```